# Future not returning anything

Tags: scala, concurrency, playframework, playframework-2.0

trying to fetch result from database and returning the future resultset. But the issue is while accessing future result i am not getting any response.

below is the code snippnet:

```
  def getAll(): Future[Iterable[Employee]] = {
  Future{
    fetchEmployees()
   }(ec)
  }

  def fetchEmployees(): Iterable[Employee]={
  var empList =  ListBuffer[Employee]()
      db.withConnection{ conn =>
        val statement = conn.createStatement()
        val rs = statement.executeQuery("Select * from Employee")
        while (rs.next()){
          println(rs.getString("EmpCode")+" "+rs.getString("FirstName")+" "+rs.getString("LastName"),rs.getString("Department"))
          val emp = Employee(rs.getString("EmpCode"),rs.getString("FirstName"),rs.getString("LastName"),rs.getString("Department"))
          empList.appended(emp)
        }
      }
   empList
 }
```

this is where trying to access return future object

```
def findAll: Future[Iterable[EmployeeResource]] = {
println("Inside resource handler")
repository.getAll().map(iterableEmp => {
  iterableEmp.foreach(emp => println(s"Name is $emp.firstName"))
  iterableEmp.map(emp=>createResource(emp))
})(ec)
```

}

Prints nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the doc for the `appended` method -- and note the term, it is not "append" (like in a command), but "appended", like *what if*...

> def appended[B >: A](elem: B): ListBuffer[B]
>
> A copy of this sequence with an element appended.

Your code:

```scala
empList.appended(emp)
```

creates a new ListBuffer, but you discard its result and your initial list buffer is never actually modified. (It is always a good idea to switch on the `-Ywarn-value-discard` scalac option!)

You need to use the `+=` operator (or the `addOne` method).